# How to release SDL_Texture from VRAM?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

My understanding about SDL_Texture is:

1. When you call SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(), SDL_Texture is located on main memory.
2. When you call SDL_RenderCopy(), the texture is located on VRAM.
3. When you call SDL_DestroyTexture(), the texture is released from VRAM and main memory.

Am I correct?

I'm making an application that create a lot of textures from image files all at once before rendering them because the image is very large and SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface() takes long time. When I render them using SDL_RenderCopy() and SDL_RenderPresent() one after another, the usage amount of VRAM increases little by little and the application gets slow after the usage reaches the max limit.

I want to release a texture from VRAM, but don't want to release it from main memory because re-creating texture takes long time. Is it possible?

This is the minimum code. It works until dedicated GPU memory usage reaches 100%. After that, it gets very slow. 
(Windows10, Visual Studio 2017, NVIDIA P6000)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    std::vector<SDL_Texture*> texture_list;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow( "", 0, 0, 7680, 4320, SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS);

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

    for ( auto ent : fs::recursive_directory_iterator("c:\\picture\\1k") ) {
        if(!fs::is_directory(ent)){
            auto f = ent.path().generic_string();
            auto surface = IMG_Load(f.c_str());
            std::cout << "file:" << f << std::endl;
            auto tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
            if(!tex){
                std::cout << "SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface error" << std::endl;
                std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
            }
            texture_list.push_back(tex);

            SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
        }
    }

    while (true) {
        for (auto tex : texture_list) {

            if(SDL_RenderClear(renderer) != 0){
                std::cout << "SDL_RenderClear error" << std::endl;
                std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
            }
            if(SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, tex, NULL, NULL) < 0){
                std::cout << "SDL_RenderCopy error" << std::endl;
                std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
            }
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

            SDL_Delay(1);
            //std::cout << cnt++ << std::endl;
            SDL_Event event;

            if(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
                std::cout << event.type << std::endl;
                switch (event.type) {
                    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                        switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
                            case SDLK_q:
                                exit(0);

                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Repeated RenderCopy doesn't increase your memory footprint. If you add some code into your quesiton (best case is minimal complete compilable verifyable example) then it might be possible to say where your memory usage comes from. It is also not clear how you measure memory usage, especially VRAM.

Comment: you shouldn't worry about implementation details that are purposely abstracted from you for various backends. Your memory usage will have little, if anything, to do with calling `SDL_RenderCopy()`. I suspect you are actually creating multiple duplicate textures.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I added code I made.

Comment: @yamasv I don't think anything wrong in given code example. Just to make sure, you tested it with exactly the code you've given and it displays something like very fast slideshow but memory usage keeps increasing with each passing frame? How do you measure VRAM usage? Is RAM usage increases too? If so, it probably is a graphics driver issue; can you try different rendering backends via e.g. `SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, "opengl");` before creating window/renderer (but after SDL_Init)?

Comment: No, it's not correct. `SDL_Texture`s always reside in VRAM (unless you're using a software renderer), as opposed to `SDL_Surface`s, which are stored in regular RAM. `SDL_RenderCopy` is just a funny name for a function that renders an image ("copies" it onto a screen).

Comment: @keltar I monitor GPU memory usage on Windows task manager. https://imgur.com/a/55Pa01B The second graph from the bottom is dedicated GPU memory usage, and the bottom one is shared GPU memory usage. The dedicated GPU memory usage start incresing from when it start rendering image, not when it starts creating texture. The application gets very slow when the usage reaches 100%.

Comment: @keltar I tried to call SDL_SetHing(SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, "opengl"); after calling SDL_init() before creating window, but nothing has changed.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you for the explanation. Does that mean that my solution doesn't work if the video card doesn't have memory enough to store all the textures?

Answer (score 0):

You have everything happening once per texture!

(Maybe you intended this, but it doesnt seem useful; there are shorter and better designs for a slideshow)

you should be calling `SDL_RenderClear` only once per main loop iteration at the beginning of your main loop. Similarly you should be calling `SDL_RenderPresent` only near the end on your main loop along with `SDL_PollEvent`

```
while (true) {
    if(SDL_RenderClear(renderer) != 0){
        std::cout << "SDL_RenderClear error" << std::endl;
        std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }

    for (auto tex : texture_list) {
        if(SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, tex, NULL, NULL) < 0){
            std::cout << "SDL_RenderCopy error" << std::endl;
            std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Delay(1);
    //std::cout << cnt++ << std::endl;
    SDL_Event event;

    if(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
        std::cout << event.type << std::endl;
        switch (event.type) {
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
                    case SDLK_q:
                        exit(0);

                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `SDL_RenderCopy` is missing a destination rectangle so each texture will all be drawn over the previous one...

If you *do* want a slideshow. You would probably be better of *not* creating all the textures upfront and try instead to build them on demand when the slide switches or creating a *single* streaming texture and updating the pixels (may not work well if your images are different sizes)

Comment: Thank you, Brad. Don't you need to call SDL_RenderPresent() every time after calling SDL_RenderCopy()? I don't want to create texture every time because each image is very large (8K, uncompressed TIFF) and SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface() takes a long time.

Comment: @yamasv No, you are supposed to only call it once per frame. I recommend you combine your images into as few texture atlases as possible, otherwise this is not going to scale very well at all. can you elaborate on what you are actually trying to accomplish? if you want a slideshow (the way your code works now), then dont worry about how slow `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` is. if you dont, then use atlases.

Comment: What I actually want to make is like a player that can play normal, fast(skip), reverse, etc. In the normal play mode, I want to play in 60 fps. My application can do them if the number of images is not so many and all the textures can be stored in VRAM. (Sorry, my English skill is not good enough to explain what I really want to do.)

Comment: @yamasv I believe you made yourself clear enough. Your current architecture wont quite allow for that (you need to get away from iterating all images; use a simple loop with only 1 clear/present/poll). I dont know how many images you you have or what size they are, but the best thing to do is put them all on one texture and then render only a portion of that texture that represents each individual image (an atlas). You may need multiple atlases to avoid texture size limits (and GPU memory). prebuild an atlas image editor or at runtime with `SDL_Surface` or an `SDL_Texture` as a render target.

Comment: @yamasv also, the way you are trying to limit the FPS wont work. That is a separate question tho.